# Setting SQL Server CE connection for a dll class library

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, connection-string, class-library, sql-server-ce-4

I can build an app using Windows Forms connecting to a SQL Server CE `.sdf` file to read and write. Now I need to do the same for a class library .dll project which intended to be a Revit Add-in so I added `app.config` and `Settings.settings` as well but in vain!

Any suggestion to properly save the connection string so it would work for multiple desktops?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just set the connection string in code??

Comment: Thank you @ErikEJ for Commenting. The problem in setting the connection this way -- String consting = "Data Source = |DataDirectory|RoomDB.sdf"-- is that it searches the "RoomDB.sdf" in the Directory where Revit is installed which off-course wouldn't be there.

Comment: I located the "RoomDB.sdf" in the same directory of the project-of the add-in- and I need the connection String to reference to that location. Is that possible?

Comment: In other words, I need the connection string to be formatted in such a way that it doesn't depend on my PC, I need it to be in a format that enables my add-in to be installed in multiple PCs without loosing the connection with the .sdf file. Please help Mr. @ErikEJ! , and to forget Thank u @marc_s for correcting my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DataDirectory, you can set the value of that in code:

```
string path = // folder path to the database file       
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

Comment: Would this succeed if I try to install the addin in other PCs?

Comment: I tried to reference to the same dll directory using the following format :               String mycon = " Data Source = \"System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)\\RoomDB.sdf";     but it gives me the following error "Format of initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 1."

Comment: To your question - yes, if you are able to locate the .sdf file!

Comment: alright , I'm afraid if I do this , Revit would have the current Data directory as the path I provided and then I will come up with endless errors of not finding its own .dll files like RevitAPI.dll

Comment: Yes, Surely. I have studied C# Fundamentals & SQL Basics with some background from the university but I love programming so recently I'm bracing my practice with the internet research and asking questions I don't know like this one. Do you have an Online C# or SQL Courses that I can follow?